# Theme background

Tags: android, styles, themes, background-color

I need to set a background color to every activitity in my app. I would prefer to set it globally. For this reason I change the style setted as application theme.

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/app_bg</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

The problem is that now all ImageViews and TextViews that have not a specified Background get the app background and not the background of parent Layout, for example

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/mmc_rl"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/mm_central_height"
    android:background="@color/main_menu_central_bg"> 

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mmc_iv_goto"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/mm_central_height"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/mm_central_height"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@drawable/button_goto_big3"  />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The ImageView has the background `app_bg` and not `main_menu_central_bg` as expected. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

include this line on the ImageView xml:

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Comment: ok thanks, the correct spelling is android:background="@android:color/transparent" without the "s" of "colors"

Comment: thanks. edited. you know. I typed by heart, those stuff happens.